# Is it correct to say the differential is the equation of the tangent line?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential, tangent-line

For example. Given function

> $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x} \Rightarrow f'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}$

> $dy = (\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3})dx$

compared to...

> $\Delta y = \frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}\Delta x$

I know its a silly questions but i am trying to have a consistent understanding of math symbology

Comment: The equation of the tangent line at a point $  \ x \ = \ a \ $ on the function curve is the linear approximation (linearization) of the function there.  The differential is useful is finding that equation.

Comment: I hope your textbook does not say "the differential is the equation of the tangent line".  If that were true, wouldn't the book say that, instead of the more complicated explanation of "differential" that is now there?

Comment: It's the equation of the tangent line in the tangent space. That is a space of differentials whose origin is at the point at which we evaluate the derivative.

Comment: @GEdgar thanks for the comment. I was considering the points on the tangent line for this delta... that one which creates a right triangle with the tangent line. But now i get it! I was distracted... this is a function dx -> dy.

Comment: Thanks you all. These comments gave me something to think. I am brand new to this forum (my first forum ever) and this is my very first question. I am learning the math-code yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Delta x$ is a small interval (think of a small "change" in $x$), then it produces a corresponding change $\Delta y$, which by definition must be given by the formula
$$
y + \Delta y = f(x + \Delta x).
$$
In other words, since $y = f(x)$, this is equivalent to
$$
\Delta y = f(x + \Delta x) - f(x). 
\label{diff} 
\tag{1}
$$
Assuming that $\Delta x \neq 0$, we can rewrite this as
$$
\Delta y = \frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} \, \Delta x. 
\label{diffquot} 
\tag{2}
$$
Notice that this is still an equation based on a *secant line* approximating the graph of the function $f$ between the points $(x, y)$ and
$(x + \Delta x, y + \Delta y)$.

When we allow $\Delta x \to 0$, the second of these two points collides with the first, so we are no longer considering a secant line connecting two points on the graph of $f$. Equation $(\ref{diff})$ makes this explicit by showing that $\Delta y \to 0$ as well.

Surprisingly though, for many nice functions, Equation $(\ref{diffquot})$ is still useful to *approximate* $\Delta y$ as long as these quantities are small.

When we let $\Delta x \to 0$, so $\Delta y \to 0$ as well, we change notation to the differentials $dx$ and $dy$, so we have
$$
dy = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} 
\frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} \, dx 
= f'(x) \, dx, 
\label{differential} 
\tag{3}
$$
which is only a statement about predicting a change $dy$ in the variable $y$ along the *tangent* line for a change $dx$ in $x$. But if $\Delta x$ is small, this is approximately equal to the actual change $\Delta y$, hence
$$
\Delta y \approx f'(x) \, \Delta x. 
$$

---

To answer your particular question, where $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ and $x \neq 0$, then
$$
dy = \tfrac13 x^{-2/3} \, dx 
$$
and
$$
\Delta y \approx \tfrac13 x^{-2/3} \, \Delta x. 
$$

[image: Secant and tangent lines on curve.]

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/i9kg3s0of4) you can play around with the what these various quantities look like interactively. (Instead of $x$ and $\Delta x$, they are called $a$ and $h$ in the graphic.)

Comment: wow! thanks for the answer, friend. I understand better the aproximation for this perspective you gave me!